# Email notifications not working for other mercurial active branches in teamcity

Tags: mercurial, branch, teamcity, email-notifications

I am not getting any email notifications for projects that are not using the default branch in mercurial instead using another branch. Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

My team just ran across this problem (with git).  Looks like it's a feature, not a bug.  [See the TeamCity wiki](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Notifications).  The TeamCity 7 documentation says the same thing.  This is documented for git as well as mercurial.

There's a ticket in the TeamCity tracker requesting for this to change. You could vote for it which might help encourage them to change it. [See the ticket.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-25487)